# IOS 7 + For force controller Orientation to Portrait

Tags: iphone, orientation, ios7

I have used below code for IO6 and below to force rotate:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if (application.statusBarOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
        [c.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:c animated:NO completion:^{
            [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
            }];
        }];
    }
}
```

But it is not working correctly on IOS7, it rotate view controller but again set blank view on screen...

Can you help me to solve this issue in IOS 7...

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    }];
```

To this:

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
```

Comment: Hi.. it is working... but previous view still in Lancape mode when i back on it and previous view interfaceOrientation = 4 and statusBarOrientation = 1 which is different. Any solution for it...

Comment: @kokx Should the previous view not support landscape? I'm not exactly sure what you are saying with = 4 and = 1, maybe use the mnemonic? You could try implementing the rotation delegates in the previous view as well?

Comment: Yes, have done it but when i back, delegate functions shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations, not call...

Comment: Blimey! Yes, this causes it to work, and actually animating either the present or dismiss causes this to work. The visual effect is slightly different though. Any idea why animating fixes this?

Comment: I think it has something to do with unbalanced calls; iOS7 probably handles the methods slightly differently, and so the view may be 'dismissed' before presented, not giving desired results. Just a hunch, though.